# structuring my database table with unique value

Tags: php, mysql, fat-free-framework

i am using Fat Free Framework to create my database driven application. i create this to easily store my test result based on the ID. the ID is a combination of letter and number like **A01** to **A100** then **B01** to **B100** and so on. Right now, i am on the letter **H**.

each of the ID is a unique column so no two ID can be the same. I am retrieving all data related to the ID like this
*http://localhost/monitor/A01*.

now my problem is, when this year (2017) come to and end, the ID will be reverted back to **A01** for 2018 data.
my table structure is as follows

```
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field         | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| monitorId     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| monitor_label | char(5)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| casting_date  | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| casting_time  | time             | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| clientId      | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| projectId     | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| gid           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| mid           | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| techId        | int(10) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| cube_size     | int(1) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| remark        | varchar(255)     | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| slump         | int(3)           | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| sample        | int(11)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data_status   | int(10) unsigned | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

the **A01** data is stored in `monitor_label`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot to express your question, but I believe you're wondering how to structure your database.

Well I see two solutions:

1) either you handle the series uniqueness in PHP and thus you just need to replace the unique index on `monitor_label` by a non-unique one

2) or you store a new `monitor_year` column in the database and replace the unique index on `monitor_label` by a composite unique index on `monitor_year,monitory_label`

Comment: sorry and yes, my question is how do structure my database so that i can keep the unique `monitor_label` but still can be use next year because every year, the `monitor_label` will revert back to **A01**. I like the idea of using composite unique index, but i have to change the route to `http://localhost/monitor/2017/A01`

Comment: sorry and yes, my question is how do structure my database so that i can keep the unique `monitor_label` but still can be use next year because every year, the `monitor_label` will revert back to **A01**. I like the idea of using composite unique index, but i have to change the route to `http://localhost/monitor/2017/A01`